# Loop infinito em java

Tags: java

Este meu código tem como finalidade renomear uma massa de arquivos para definir o seguinte padrão: Todas os nomes compostos, as palavras devem iniciar em maiúscula. Primeiro eu dou um substring para nomes que só tem uma palavra e depois faço um `while` para os nomes compostos porém não sai do `while`, alguém pode me ajudar a entender o porque ? Estou tentando renomear muitos arquivos.

```
import java.io.File;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File diretorio = new File("/home/douglas/roms");
        File[] arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();

        for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
            String nome;
            String extencao = ".gba";
            nome = arquivo.getName();
            nome = nome.toLowerCase();
            nome = nome.substring(0, nome.indexOf(extencao));
            nome = cortarTrecho(nome, " # gba");
            String primeira = nome.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            String restante = nome.substring(1);
            nome = primeira + restante;

            while (nome.contains(" ")) {

                String nomeFinal = "";
                String partes[] = nome.split("\\s+");

                for (int i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) {
                    nomeFinal += "*" + partes[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + partes[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
                }
                nomeFinal = nomeFinal.substring(1) + extencao;
                System.out.println(nomeFinal);
            }

        }

    }

    public static String cortarTrecho(String nome, String trecho) {

        int index = nome.indexOf(trecho);
        nome = nome.substring(0, index);
        return nome;

    }

}
```

Comment: Precisa ver o que deseja fazer, a condição de saída envolve analisar a variável `nome`, como ela nunca muda dentro do laço, quando ela entra, não sai mais. Precisa ter outra condição ou mudar o `nome` para que em algum momento atenda essa condição. Não sei nem se deveria ter esse `while` aí, tenho a impressão que nem precisa, deve um `if`, ou nem isso é preciso. Não escrevi uma resposta porque sequer sei o que deve fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era simples, só atribuir o valor de nomeFinal para nome.

```
nome = nomeFinal;
```

Comment: Isso não faz muito sentido, na verdade outras coisas no código não fazem muito sentido, ou pleo menos é um desperdício.

Comment: @bigown entendi, eu estou aprendendo aos poucos ainda rsrs, mas obrigado.

Comment: Você pode alterar um pouco sua pergunta para que o @bigown possa te dar uma dicas do que não faz sentido e como corrigir

Comment: @bigown pronto.